# Different result with DISTINCT and GROUP BY

Tags: sqlite, group-by, distinct

I execute these 2 queries in my DB. The first one returns 1 record and the second one returns 2241 (as I expected). I ask the same thing but in two  different way. In the first, I use `DISTINCT` and in the second I use "GROUP BY". Aren't these the same?

```
/*returns 1 record*/
SELECT DISTINCT INVENTORY.location, INVENTORY.label, INVENTORY.version, SUM(INVENTORY.quantity) AS total, LABELS.description, LABELS.customer , LABELS.label 
FROM INVENTORY 
INNER JOIN LABELS 
ON INVENTORY.label = LABELS.label 
AND INVENTORY.version = LABELS.version 
WHERE INVENTORY.location = 1

/*returns 2241  record*/
SELECT Inventory.location, Inventory.label, Inventory.version, SUM(INVENTORY.quantity) AS total, Labels.description, Labels.customer, LABELS.label 
FROM Inventory 
INNER JOIN LABELS 
ON Inventory.label = Labels.label 
AND  Inventory.version =  Labels.version 
WHERE Inventory.location = 1
GROUP BY Inventory.label, Inventory.Version
```

Comment: Actually: both are invalid SQL The first one is missing the required `group by` completely, the second doesn't group on all non-aggregate columns. I am surprised that SQLite even accepts that.

Comment: I don't get any errors ...!!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Since when DISTINCT requires a GROUP BY?

Comment: @m0skit0: `distinct` doesn't but the `sum()` does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your queries are invalid according to ANSI SQL, but that didn't stop Oracle from releasing MySQL, nor did it stop you from writing these queries.  Here is a valid version of the two queries you attempted:

```
SELECT Inventory.location,
       Inventory.label,
       Inventory.version,
       SUM(INVENTORY.quantity) AS total,
       Labels.description,
       Labels.customer,
       LABELS.label 
FROM Inventory 
INNER JOIN LABELS 
    ON Inventory.label   = Labels.label AND
       Inventory.version = Labels.version 
WHERE Inventory.location = 1
GROUP BY Inventory.location,
         Inventory.label,
         Inventory.version,
         Labels.description,
         Labels.customer,
         LABELS.label
```

Key points here are that every column which appears in the `SELECT` clause either also appears in the `GROUP BY` clause *or* appears inside an aggregate function, such as `SUM`.

Your queries ran on SQLite because it is compatible with MySQL which is lax in imposing strictness on queries.

Comment: To be fair: it was not Oracle that introduced the broken `group by` implementation in MySQL